# Listener to tell if a table has an element in it

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I'm working on a Java project using SWT/JFace. I have a `Table` that is using a `TableViewer`. The table will only ever have 0 or 1 items in it (depending on the data it's viewing...). Is there a way to listen to this table to see if it has an item in it or not. I have been using `ISelectionChangedListener` on the viewer so far, but it doesn't work perfectly as the user must click on the item to register the change. Ideally the listener would be triggered every time an item is put into or removed from the table. I've looked around, but can't find what I need.

Anyone out there know what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly based on this, "table will only ever have 0 or 1 items in it", a simple work around is to use a `PaintListener`, this works even if the window is hidden behind other windows. The **major** drawback is when the content is not visible on the UI (like when `TableItem` is accessible via scrolling) then it **won't** work. The solution works on Win7 and with eclipse 3.7.2.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class TableTest {
    static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                System.out.println(((Table)e.widget).getItemCount() > 0);
            }
        });

        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        column.setWidth(180);
        column.setText("Test Column");

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        button.setText("Add item");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                item.setText("" + counter++);
                if(counter > 10) {
                    table.clearAll();
                    counter = 0;
                } 
            }
        });

        display.timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(table.isDisposed()) return;
                TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                item.setText("" + counter++);
                if(counter > 10) {
                    table.clearAll();
                    counter = 0;
                }

                display.timerExec(1000, this);
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(220, 300);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Note:** The [LVN_INSERTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not supported in SWT `Table` widget. Check the `windowProc` method in the `Table` widget.